# How do I install MATLAB R2012a?

Tags: installation, permissions, matlab

I have downloaded MATLAB R2012a for Unix platform and i want to install it on my ubuntu 11.10.
To install i try this command:

```
/<matlab_installation_file_directory>/install
```

and it says:

```
install: missing file operand
```

According to it's manual i must give it an input file, So i create an input file like this to install in 'Stand Alone' mode:

> destinationFolder=usr/local/R2012a
>
> fileInstallationKey=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
>
> agreeToLicense=yes
>
> outputFile=/tmp/mathworks_usr.log
>
> mode=interactive
>
> activationPropertiesFile=home/.../lic_standalone.dat

Acctually i'm not sure in "activationPropertiesFile" field what file is required, so i supposed it requires license file. I saved this file as txt format in the same directory which installation files are.

Then i tried this command:

```
install -inputFile my_input_file.txt
```

and it gets this error:

```
install: invalid option -- 'i'
```

I know there is some helps in other websites and also some questions here about this topic, but i can't figure out what's the problem, Please help me, i'm a real noob on linux .

Thank you guys

UPDATE:

> in properties of the install file i checked the item "Allow executing file as Program", now it's like this:  [image: install properties]

after that i can run install file by clicking on it or by typing *./install* in terminal. but in both ways i get this:

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
eval: 1: /tmp/mathworks_xxxx/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished
```

in third line xxxx is a random number every time like 6370 or 5310 ... .
why i have not permission? what should i do?

UPDATE:

using Mahesh help i tried these commands:

```
sudo chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install -v
```

the result is:

```
Preparing installation files ...
->  DVD                 = /home/mehdi/qBT_dir/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au
->  ARCH                = glnx86
->  DISPLAY             = :0.0
->  TESTONLY            = 0
->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_6114/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre
->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_6114/bin/glnx86
 
Command to run:
/tmp/mathworks_6114/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java  -splash:"/home/mehdi/qBT_dir/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_6114/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_6114/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_6114/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_6114/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_6114/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_6114/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/mehdi/qBT_dir/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_6114" 
 
Installing ...
eval: 1: /tmp/mathworks_6114/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished
```

UPDATE:

Last thing to do is go into /matlab-install-files/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java and :

```
sudo chmod +x ./java
```

and then go back to installation files directory and run install by:

```
./install
```

or

```
sudo ./install
```

and it will work :-)

Thank you all specially "Mahesh" and "John"

Comment: what does `install --help` returns ?

Comment: A rare case when the question itself contains more helpful information than its answers :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something's wrong here. I've installed Matlab R2012a, and the install file does not require any input file.

This should work.

Command line way.

- Open Terminal
- cd into Matlab directory ( which has the install file and is shown in your screenshot)
- `sudo chmod +x ./install`
- `sudo ./install`
- This will open a window, from where you will be able to proceed yourself.

GUI way:

- type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. this opens the `run` dialog
- type `gksudo nautilus` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
- open the Matlab directory (as shown in your screenshot)
- check if install file has execute permissions (as in your screenshot)
- Double click install. You will get a window asking you wether to display or run.
- Click on Run
- you should be able to find your way from here. this opens a window with necessary instructions.

as you see, The Command line way is easier and safer.. ;)

This is guaranteed to work.
And just so you know, when you executed install, as described in your question, `/usr/bin/install` must have got executed. It is probably the one that complained of a missing file operand.

Comment: thank you but i keep getting the same error, (permission denied).

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Can you update your question with any errors/messages displayed when trying the command-line way by running `sudo ./install -v` after cd-ing into the matlab directory?

Answer (score 4):

For the error:

```
eval: 1: /tmp/mathworks_11425/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
```

You have to give permissions for the java to run (credits to http://kittipatkampa.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/matlab-on-ubuntu-from-install-make-launching-icon-to-uninstall/ )

After proceeding the steps by Mahesh, go to the folder

```
cd sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/ (the folder that appears in your error message)
```

and then

```
chmod +x java
```

Ready to go. Go back to where your install file is and type

```
sudo sh install
```

The setup will (hopefully) launch.

Comment: yes it worked, installation goes to 100%, now the problem is how can i launch it ?

Comment: you can find matlab in dash (if using Unity UI). If you cant find it there, Alt+F2 to get run dialog, and type `matlab` and hit enter. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly remember how I installed Matlab (R2011a), but I believe it has a wizard you can follow. That way you can login with your mathworks credentials. iirc it is important that the folder `/usr/local/MATLAB/` is writable before the installer begins.

Maybe just run `install` from nautilus?

Comment: I check the path **/usr/local/**. neither this is writable nor lots of other folders although i am admin(i think!). what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have more problems once you complete the install process using Mahesh's comment (chmod a+x on the folder).

So, I recommend to install the matlab-support package, which will set-up the missing dependencies, paths and scripts, and also will install a shortcut (x.desktop).