# Problem in MATLAB installation with java (install: 1: eval: Permission denied)

Tags: matlab

I executed this command in a terminal by going to the folder where I placed the installation file.

```
santiago@CHAPA:~/Descargas/Matlab/MATLAB$ sudo sh install
```

but this showed in the terminal

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_6992/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the installation directory do this

```
$ cd java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin 
$ chmod +x java
```

basically you have to convert the files in  `~/Descargas/Matlab/MATLAB/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin` directory into executables.

after this continue with the normal installation from installation directory

```
$ sudo sh install
```

Comment: thanks...  but with the firs line i get this
 
bash: cd: java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin: No existe el archivo o el directorio

Comment: Actually it should be **cd sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin** and then chmod.. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here and in this post: [How do I install MATLAB R2012a?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120801/how-do-i-install-matlab-r2012a) did not help unfortunately.

For me this procedure worked -- Install instructions:

1) copy DVD content into a folder in home - e.g. **MatInstall**

2) change directory to folder with iso content:

```
cd MatInstall
```

3) make install and java executable:

```
chmod u+x install
chmod u+x sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java
```

4) create MatLabTemp directory in home:

```
mkdir $HOME/MatLabTemp
```

5) open a terminal and type the installation command:

```
$HOME/MatInstall/install -javadir $HOME/MatInstall/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/ -root $HOME/MatInstall/ -tmpdir $HOME/MatLabTemp
```

(
with this command we tell the Matlab Installer manually where to look for the data, temp directory and java)

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped. I would recomment using sudo on the last command, since it will need to create a default folder in /usr/local

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this Problem!

Got to change 'execute permission' on 2 files in the folder you create on your PC before installing the program :

install in the default Folder

java in /Matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin

To do so go on each file and: right-click -> Properties -> Go on the permission features and check the executable box. And it's Done!

./install

Answer (score 0):

The permission denial will tell you the file you need to make executable.  I download 2015a Matlab using this advise just changing a different file to executable.

java in /Matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin

To do so go on each file and: right-click -> Properties -> Go on the permission features and check the executable box. And it's Done!

./install