# How to mount .iso file on hard drive

Tags: software-installation

I'm right now in some troubles. I've MATLAB R2012b.iso which sizes 5.25 GB.

I tried to mount it using Furius and K3b.

But when I put DVD+R Double Layer in cd-rom, it says "Uable to mount, Location is already mounted."

What to do.

Comment: you Need to Mount it For using now ? or you need to Burn it to a DVD ?

Comment: Yes i want to use it now. @ Babin   I don'e know how to put it on flash drive. @ Karel

Comment: A general question about installing MatLab might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120801/how-do-i-install-matlab-r2012a

Answer (score 0):

If it's an iso image you can mount this file the following way:

```
mount -t iso9660 /path/to/file.iso /mnt
```

To check if it's an iso image type:

```
file /path/to/file.iso
/path/to/file.iso: # ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'Ubuntu 13.10 i386               ' (bootable)
```

This above is an example of an Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop iso file. As you can see it's an ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem.