# Installing Matlab on ubuntu 12.04 32 bits

Tags: 12.04, java, matlab, jre

I have been trying to install Matlab2012a, matlab2012b and Matlab2013a for like 4 hours, triedto fix my prospective errors regarding the posts [2012a](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120801/how-do-i-install-matlab-r2012a), [Ubuntu-Matlab Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB) and [Matlab-central](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/42988-installing-matlab-2012a-in-ubuntu-12-04-java-problem). But either i am recieving an error while the installation GUI pops-up with the error :

```
The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close. You may want to try re-installing your product(s). More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_amir.log
```

On the other hand for 2012a.
and the errors for 2012b and 2013a is :

`Installing ...
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardModule.provideDisplayProperties(WizardModule.java:60)
  while locating com.mathworks.instutil.DisplayProperties
  at com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.ComponentsModule.providePaintStrategy(ComponentsModule.java:76)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.PaintStrategy
    for parameter 4 at com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.SwingComponentFactoryImpl.<init>(SwingComponentFactoryImpl.java:110)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.SwingComponentFactoryImpl
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.components.SwingComponentFactory
    for parameter 1 at com.mathworks.wizard.ui.WizardUIImpl.<init>(WizardUIImpl.java:65)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.WizardUIImpl
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.WizardUI annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=BaseWizardUI)
  at com.mathworks.wizard.ui.UIModule.provideWizardUI(UIModule.java:50)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ui.WizardUI
    for parameter 0 at com.mathworks.wizard.ExceptionHandlerImpl.<init>(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:22)
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ExceptionHandlerImpl
  while locating com.mathworks.wizard.ExceptionHandler

1 error
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:767)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:793)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.startWizard(WizardLauncher.java:160)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardLauncher.start(WizardLauncher.java:75)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.AbstractLauncher.launch(AbstractLauncher.java:27)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.AbstractLauncher.launchStandalone(AbstractLauncher.java:18)
    at com.mathworks.professionalinstaller.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:101)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.mathworks.instutil.JNIException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /tmp/mathworks_7417/bin/glnxa64/libinstutil.so
    at com.mathworks.instutil.NativeUtility.loadNativeLibrary(NativeUtility.java:39)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.NativeUtility.<init>(NativeUtility.java:24)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.DisplayPropertiesImpl.<init>(DisplayPropertiesImpl.java:10)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.WizardModule.provideDisplayProperties(WizardModule.java:67)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /tmp/mathworks_7417/bin/glnxa64/libinstutil.so
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1842)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
    at com.mathworks.instutil.NativeUtility.loadNativeLibrary(NativeUtility.java:37)
    ... 62 more
Finished
```

I have tried to:

1- re-install java run-time 6 and then 7.
2- pass the java-path to the install with :

```
-javadir
```

3- use the force to install on 32 bits as :

```
sh install -glnx86 -v -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre
```

But it seems none of them have worked so far. any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

I took the time to download the same version you mentioned and did the guide I wrote in [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

I also followed on [How do I install MATLAB R2012a?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120801/how-do-i-install-matlab-r2012a?lq=1) but the answer did not work.

I then went to the appdb list to see [Matlab](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=49)

The program or at least this version is not working correctly. So for the time I will keep on digging since this is one of the top apps and try to offer good support for, but for the moment is not working with the 1.6.x or 1.7.x versions.

I would suggest to use a lower version (Wine 1.5.x) if it is possible or wait until I update this answer with a more recent test that actually works. But at least for now, Matlab 2012 is not working.

Your other way is to use Virtualbox and then run MatLab from there. Just in case, to copy MatLab from Ubuntu to the virtualbox in case you do try it is by reading this guide:  [Sharing between Host and Guest in Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81757/sharing-between-host-and-guest-in-virtualbox/81816#81816)

Comment: thanks buddy for the update, Ok I am on it. will try to install 2011a and b and see if they work or not

Comment: @Amir Will appreciate it. It will help me with the Scientific section am working on for Wine support.

Comment: but in general, due to inconsistency of the scripts between linux bash and windows systems, I prefer to make it run on Ubuntu to be able to be more sync with the other guys in our research group.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by:

```
com.mathworks.instutil.JNIException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load
```

Library:

```
/tmp/mathworks_7417/bin/glnxa64/libinstutil.so
```

I think the problem is above, since you tried to install on 32bit operating system, yet the library is 64 bits. That's end of my research, I don't know yet how to solve it, but I know that it can be solved. I had installed Matlab 2013a on Mandriva 2010 several months ago. I lost it because hard disk crashed, and now try to remember how to install it again.