# Installation of MATLAB 2013a in 13.10 trouble

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I've been looking around for solutions to this and can't really seem to find a good answer so I thought I'd try this. I'm trying to install MATLAB 2013a on Saucy Salamander. I have all the files already downloaded and extracted to my Desktop. The installation files are for Linux 64 bit. This is what I'm doing and getting on the terminal (keep in mind I'm completely new to Linux and Ubuntu):

```
sudo ~/Desktop/matlab/install -v
[sudo] password:
sudo: /home/(myname)/Desktop/matlab/install: command not found
```

I tried doing things differently by moving the MATLAB folder to a different location (i.e. Downloads) and trying this:

```
cd ~/Downloads/matlab
sudo ./install
[sudo] password:
sudo: /home/(myname)/Downloads/matlab/install: command not found
```

If you guys know a better solution/what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Drop the 'sudo' in front of the commands.

Comment: I tried that and I get "permission denied"

Comment: Remove everything. You have mixed permissions. Do not use sudo next time.

Comment: sorry i'm not sure I follow? are you saying I should uninstall MATLAB and start over? What does "mixed permissions" mean?

Comment: Try in 64 bit ubuntu OS. Unless you can't...

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer to your question instead of making it a part of the question. This prevents the question from being marked as answered, among others.

Answer (score 1):

*Reposting the solution provided by the OP in the question*

---

Alright! After doing a little bit of digging, I figured out how to do it! Here's the step by step method to (hopefully) solve the issue for anyone having the same problems:

If you have the .tar.gz file for MATLAB, be sure to right click it and extract it to folder (I did this in ~/Downloads).

Open terminal and type the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads/(matlabfolder)  
sudo chmod +x ./install  
sudo ./install
```

You will get an error that says:

```
eval:1:/tmp/mathworks_6114/sys/java/jre/glnxa86/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
```

Then, navigate to that directory and do the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads/(matlabfolder)/sys/java/jre/glnxa86/jre/bin
sudo chmod +x ./java
```

Then, go back to the install directory that you went to initially:

```
cd ~/Downloads/(matlabfolder)
sudo ./install
```

That should launch the MATLAB installer! If you find my instructions unclear, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120801/how-do-i-install-matlab-r2012a?rq=1) is where I got my info!

For those who are wondering, I think that the **chmod +x** function basically makes the file you specify to be *executable*.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the install file actually has executable permissions. If not, run the command    `chmod a+x install` 
and then try `sudo ./install` again.

You may get an error *`./install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_4880/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied`*, then run the command

*`chmod +x ./sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java`* and then try the *`sudo ./install`* again.

Answer (score -1):

I have also received permission denied at  other folder line /sys/glnxa64/install_unix . So go the folder and open terminal. change permission using chmod +x install_unix.