# Installation of MatLAB on Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: matlab

I  did what i was told in [[Installation of MATLAB 2013a in 13.10 trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403964/installation-of-matlab-2013a-in-13-10-trouble][1]) ]but then I got this error message. I am trying to install it in a Lubuntu 15.10 version laptop.

```
    [ user ] [~] >   cd  matlab                                                   []
    [ user ] [~/matlab] > sudo chmod +x ./install                                 []
    [ user ] [~/matlab] > sudo ./install                                          []
    Preparing installation files ...
    Installing ...
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003ac0, pid=7747, tid=139673856186112
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_60-b19) (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # [thread 139673987352320 also had an error][thread 139673988404992 also had an error]
    C
      0x0000000000003ac0
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /home/prn/matlab/hs_err_pid7747.log
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #
    Finished
```

Can someone plz tell me how to rectify this ASAP

**UPDATE:**
I was somehow able to install MatLAB in the laptop but now i am unable to open the application from the terminal as well as from the the run window... How do i rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the 2 workarounds which I have used Workaround

You can force MATLAB to load the newer version of the library provided by the operating system, by following these instructions:

Identify the location where MATLAB is installed
Navigate to the sys/os/glnxa64 directory within this installation folder
Rename libstdc++.so.6 library to libstdc++.so.6.old

This is the 2nd workaround for R2015b and before

`sudo apt-get install matlab-support`

Both of these work.