# Unable to install Matlab 2011 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: matlab

Setup Read file says that go to mount folder and type install -inputFile

I did all these things...
But nothing happen and terminal shows that

```
root@LABE-1294-0-170:/media/matlab# install -inputFile installer_input
install: invalid option -- 'i'
Try `install --help' for more information
```

After that i copied all the files into a folder and than give 777 permission to all the files which are present in the matlab folder.
But nothing happen.

```
root@LABE-1294-0-170:/home/umeshkumar/Desktop/mat# ./install
installer                install_guide_ja_JP.pdf  
installer_input.txt      install_guide.pdf        
root@LABE-1294-0-170:/home/umeshkumar/Desktop/mat# ./installer
./installer: line 169: product.Aerospace_Blockset: command not found
./installer: line 170: product.Aerospace_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 171: product.Bioinformatics_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 172: product.Communications_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 173: product.Computer_Vision_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 174: product.Control_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 175: product.Curve_Fitting_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 176: product.DO_Qualification_Kit: command not found
./installer: line 177: product.DSP_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 178: product.Data_Acquisition_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 179: product.Database_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 180: product.Datafeed_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 181: product.EDA_Simulator_Link: command not found
./installer: line 182: product.Econometrics_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 183: product.Embedded_Coder: command not found
./installer: line 184: product.Filter_Design_HDL_Coder: command not found
./installer: line 185: product.Financial_Derivatives_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 186: product.Financial_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 187: product.Fixed_Income_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 188: product.Fixed_Point_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 189: product.Fuzzy_Logic_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 190: product.Gauges_Blockset: command not found
./installer: line 191: product.Global_Optimization_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 192: product.IEC_Certification_Kit: command not found
./installer: line 193: product.Image_Acquisition_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 194: product.Image_Processing_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 195: product.Instrument_Control_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 196: product.MATLAB: command not found
./installer: line 197: product.MATLAB_Builder_EX: command not found
./installer: line 198: product.MATLAB_Builder_JA: command not found
./installer: line 199: product.MATLAB_Builder_NE: command not found
./installer: line 200: product.MATLAB_Coder: command not found
./installer: line 201: product.MATLAB_Compiler: command not found
./installer: line 202: product.MATLAB_Distributed_Computing_Server: command not found
./installer: line 203: product.MATLAB_Report_Generator: command not found
./installer: line 204: product.Mapping_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 205: product.Model_Predictive_Control_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 206: product.Model_Based_Calibration_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 207: product.Neural_Network_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 208: product.OPC_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 209: product.Optimization_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 210: product.Parallel_Computing_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 211: product.Partial_Differential_Equation_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 212: product.Phased_Array_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 213: product.RF_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 214: product.Real_Time_Windows_Target: command not found
./installer: line 215: product.Robust_Control_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 216: product.Signal_Processing_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 217: product.SimBiology: command not found
./installer: line 218: product.SimDriveline: command not found
./installer: line 219: product.SimElectronics: command not found
./installer: line 220: product.SimEvents: command not found
./installer: line 221: product.SimHydraulics: command not found
./installer: line 222: product.SimMechanics: command not found
./installer: line 223: product.SimPowerSystems: command not found
./installer: line 224: product.SimRF: command not found
./installer: line 225: product.Simscape: command not found
./installer: line 226: product.Simulink: command not found
./installer: line 227: product.Simulink_3D_Animation: command not found
./installer: line 228: product.Simulink_Coder: command not found
./installer: line 229: product.Simulink_Control_Design: command not found
./installer: line 230: product.Simulink_Design_Optimization: command not found
./installer: line 231: product.Simulink_Design_Verifier: command not found
./installer: line 232: product.Simulink_Fixed_Point: command not found
./installer: line 233: product.Simulink_HDL_Coder: command not found
./installer: line 234: product.Simulink_PLC_Coder: command not found
./installer: line 235: product.Simulink_Report_Generator: command not found
./installer: line 236: product.Simulink_Verification_and_Validation: command not found
./installer: line 237: product.Spreadsheet_Link_EX: command not found
./installer: line 238: product.Stateflow: command not found
./installer: line 239: product.Statistics_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 240: product.Symbolic_Math_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 241: product.System_Identification_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 242: product.SystemTest: command not found
./installer: line 243: product.Vehicle_Network_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 244: product.Wavelet_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 245: product.xPC_Target: command not found
./installer: line 246: product.xPC_Target_Embedded_Option: command not found
```

I made changes in install file for the automatic installation. Here is my file

Use this file to specify parameters required by the installer at runtime.

Instructions for using this file.

1. Create a copy of this template file and fill in the required 
   information.  Uncomment and set desired values; all available values 
   are listed below.
2. Launch the installer from the command line, using the -inputFile option
   to specify the name of your installer initialization file.

   (Windows) setup.exe -inputFile 
   (Mac/Unix) install -inputFile

NOTE: If you want to run the activation application in silent
mode immediately after the installer completes, you must create
an activation initialization file and specify its name as the
value of the activationPropertiesFile= option. You can also
pass the name of the activation initialization file to the
installer using the -activationPropertiesFile command line
option.

SPECIFY INSTALLATION FOLDER

Example:

```
   (Windows) destinationFolder=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\RXXXX
   (Unix) destinationFolder=/usr/local/RXXXX
   (Mac) destinationFolder=/Applications

destinationFolder=/usr/local/matlab
```

SPECIFY FILE INSTALLATION KEY

Example: fileInstallationKey=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.....

```
fileInstallationKey=27148-10273-27823-12342-16466
```

ACCEPT LICENSE AGREEMENT

You must agree to the license agreement to install MathWorks products.
The license agreement can be found in the license.txt file at the
root level of the installation DVD.

Example: agreeToLicense=yes

```
agreeToLicense=yes
```

SPECIFY OUTPUT LOG

Specify full path of file into which you want the results of the 
installation to be recorded.

Example:

```
       (Windows) outputFile=C:\TEMP\mathworks_<user_name>.log
       (Unix/Mac) outputFile=/tmp/mathworks_<user_name>.log

 outputFile=/tmp/mat/matlab.log
```

SPECIFY INSTALLER MODE

interactive: Run the installer GUI, waiting for user input on all dialog boxes.

silent:      Run the installer without displaying the GUI.

automated:   Run the installer GUI, displaying all dialog boxes, but only 
             waiting for user input on dialogs that are missing required input.

Set to interactive, silent, or automated.

```
mode=interactive
```

SPECIFY LENGTH OF TIME DIALOG BOXES ARE DISPLAYED

Specify how long the installer dialog boxes are displayed, in milliseconds.

NOTE: Use this value only if you set the installer mode to automated.

By default, the dialog boxes display on the screen for one second.

Example: (To specify a value of 1 second.) automatedModeTimeout=1000

```
automatedModeTimeout=
```

SPECIFY ACTIVATION PROPERTIES FILE (For non-network license types only)

Enter the path to an existing file that contains properties to configure
the activation process.

```
activationPropertiesFile=
```

Begin: Options for Network License Types

SPECIFY PATH TO LICENSE FILE (Required for network license types only)

This value is required when installing either the License Manager or when 
installing as a Network End-User
Example:

```
       (Windows) licensePath=C:\TEMP\license.dat
       (Unix) licensePath=/tmp/license.dat
licensePath=
```

CHOOSE TO INSTALL LICENSE MANAGER (For network license types only)

Installs license manager files to disk.

NOTE: You only need to install the license manager files
on your license server.

Set to true or false.

```
lmgrFiles=
```

INSTALL LICENSE MANAGER AS A SERVICE (For network license types only)

Configure the license manager as a service on Windows.

NOTE: Not applicable for Unix or Mac.

NOTE: The lmgr_files option (set in previous step) must also be set to true.

Set to true or false.

```
lmgrService=
```

End: Options for Network License Types

Begin - Windows Only Options

CHOOSE TO CREATE WINDOWS DESKTOP SHORTCUT

Set to true if you would like the installer to create a desktop shortcut icon
when MATLAB is installed or false if you don't want the shortcut created.
Set to true or false.

```
desktopShortcut=
```

CHOOSE TO ADD SHORTCUT TO WINDOWS START MENU

Set to true if you would like the installer to create a Start Menu shortcut 
icon when MATLAB is installed or false if you don't want the shortcut created.
Set to true or false.

```
startMenuShortcut=
```

End - Windows Only Options

SPECIFY PRODUCTS YOU WANT TO INSTALL

By default, the installer installs all the products and 
documentation for which you are licensed. Products you are not licensed for 
are not installed, even if they are listed here.

To install specific products, uncomment the line for the product(s) you want
to install.

```
product.Aerospace_Blockset
product.Aerospace_Toolbox
product.Bioinformatics_Toolbox
product.Communications_System_Toolbox
product.Computer_Vision_System_Toolbox
product.Control_System_Toolbox
product.Curve_Fitting_Toolbox
product.DO_Qualification_Kit
product.DSP_System_Toolbox
product.Data_Acquisition_Toolbox
product.Database_Toolbox
product.Datafeed_Toolbox
product.EDA_Simulator_Link
product.Econometrics_Toolbox
product.Embedded_Coder
product.Filter_Design_HDL_Coder
product.Financial_Derivatives_Toolbox
product.Financial_Toolbox
product.Fixed_Income_Toolbox
product.Fixed_Point_Toolbox
product.Fuzzy_Logic_Toolbox
product.Gauges_Blockset
product.Global_Optimization_Toolbox
product.IEC_Certification_Kit
product.Image_Acquisition_Toolbox
product.Image_Processing_Toolbox
product.Instrument_Control_Toolbox
product.MATLAB
product.MATLAB_Builder_EX
product.MATLAB_Builder_JA
product.MATLAB_Builder_NE
product.MATLAB_Coder
product.MATLAB_Compiler
product.MATLAB_Distributed_Computing_Server
product.MATLAB_Report_Generator
product.Mapping_Toolbox
product.Model_Predictive_Control_Toolbox
product.Model_Based_Calibration_Toolbox
product.Neural_Network_Toolbox
product.OPC_Toolbox
product.Optimization_Toolbox
product.Parallel_Computing_Toolbox
product.Partial_Differential_Equation_Toolbox
product.Phased_Array_System_Toolbox
product.RF_Toolbox
product.Real_Time_Windows_Target
product.Robust_Control_Toolbox
product.Signal_Processing_Toolbox
product.SimBiology
product.SimDriveline
product.SimElectronics
product.SimEvents
product.SimHydraulics
product.SimMechanics
product.SimPowerSystems
product.SimRF
product.Simscape
product.Simulink
product.Simulink_3D_Animation
product.Simulink_Coder
product.Simulink_Control_Design
product.Simulink_Design_Optimization
product.Simulink_Design_Verifier
product.Simulink_Fixed_Point
product.Simulink_HDL_Coder
product.Simulink_PLC_Coder
product.Simulink_Report_Generator
product.Simulink_Verification_and_Validation
product.Spreadsheet_Link_EX
product.Stateflow
product.Statistics_Toolbox
product.Symbolic_Math_Toolbox
product.System_Identification_Toolbox
product.SystemTest
product.Vehicle_Network_Toolbox
product.Wavelet_Toolbox
product.xPC_Target
product.xPC_Target_Embedded_Option
```

But it shows error that:

```
root@LABE-1294-0-170:/home/umeshkumar/Desktop/mat# ./installer
./installer: line 169: product.Aerospace_Blockset: command not found
./installer: line 170: product.Aerospace_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 171: product.Bioinformatics_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 172: product.Communications_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 173: product.Computer_Vision_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 174: product.Control_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 175: product.Curve_Fitting_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 176: product.DO_Qualification_Kit: command not found
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120801/how-do-i-install-matlab-r2012a (for Matlab 2012a but looks like the same issue)

Comment: @chronitis but i am unable to execute that install file after giving 777 permission to that file.

Comment: have you set the owner to your user ?

Comment: i am a root user now ....