# Matlab 2011a installer show error in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: matlab

I made changes in install file for the automatic installation. Here is my file

```
Use this file to specify parameters required by the installer at runtime.

Instructions for using this file.

1. Create a copy of this template file and fill in the required 
   information.  Uncomment and set desired values; all available values 
   are listed below.

2. Launch the installer from the command line, using the -inputFile option
   to specify the name of your installer initialization file. 

   (Windows) setup.exe -inputFile <file_name>
   (Mac/Unix) install -inputFile <file_name>

NOTE: If you want to run the activation application in silent
mode immediately after the installer completes, you must create
an activation initialization file and specify its name as the
value of the activationPropertiesFile= option. You can also
pass the name of the activation initialization file to the
installer using the -activationPropertiesFile command line
option. 

SPECIFY INSTALLATION FOLDER

Example: 
       (Windows) destinationFolder=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\RXXXX
       (Unix) destinationFolder=/usr/local/RXXXX
       (Mac) destinationFolder=/Applications


 destinationFolder=/usr/local/matlab


SPECIFY FILE INSTALLATION KEY 

Example: fileInstallationKey=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.....

 fileInstallationKey=27148-10273-27823-12342-16466


ACCEPT LICENSE AGREEMENT  

You must agree to the license agreement to install MathWorks products.
The license agreement can be found in the license.txt file at the
root level of the installation DVD.

Example: agreeToLicense=yes

 agreeToLicense=yes


SPECIFY OUTPUT LOG

Specify full path of file into which you want the results of the 
installation to be recorded.

Example: 
           (Windows) outputFile=C:\TEMP\mathworks_<user_name>.log
           (Unix/Mac) outputFile=/tmp/mathworks_<user_name>.log

 outputFile=/tmp/mat/matlab.log

SPECIFY INSTALLER MODE 

interactive: Run the installer GUI, waiting for user input on all dialog boxes.

silent:      Run the installer without displaying the GUI.

automated:  Run the installer GUI, displaying all dialog boxes, but only 
            waiting for user input on dialogs that are missing required input.

Set to interactive, silent, or automated.

 mode=interactive

SPECIFY LENGTH OF TIME DIALOG BOXES ARE DISPLAYED

Specify how long the installer dialog boxes are displayed, in milliseconds.

NOTE: Use this value only if you set the installer mode to automated.

By default, the dialog boxes display on the screen for one second.

Example: (To specify a value of 1 second.) automatedModeTimeout=1000

automatedModeTimeout=

SPECIFY ACTIVATION PROPERTIES FILE (For non-network license types only)
Enter the path to an existing file that contains properties to configure
the activation process.

activationPropertiesFile=

Begin: Options for Network License Types

SPECIFY PATH TO LICENSE FILE (Required for network license types only)

This value is required when installing either the License Manager or when 
installing as a Network End-User
Example: 
           (Windows) licensePath=C:\TEMP\license.dat
           (Unix) licensePath=/tmp/license.dat
licensePath=

CHOOSE TO INSTALL LICENSE MANAGER (For network license types only)

Installs license manager files to disk.

NOTE: You only need to install the license manager files
on your license server.

Set to true or false.

lmgrFiles=

INSTALL LICENSE MANAGER AS A SERVICE (For network license types only)

Configure the license manager as a service on Windows.

NOTE: Not applicable for Unix or Mac.

NOTE: The lmgr_files option (set in previous step) must also be set to true.

Set to true or false.

lmgrService=

End: Options for Network License Types 

Begin - Windows Only Options

CHOOSE TO CREATE WINDOWS DESKTOP SHORTCUT

Set to true if you would like the installer to create a desktop shortcut icon
when MATLAB is installed or false if you don't want the shortcut created.
Set to true or false.

desktopShortcut=

CHOOSE TO ADD SHORTCUT TO WINDOWS START MENU

Set to true if you would like the installer to create a Start Menu shortcut 
icon when MATLAB is installed or false if you don't want the shortcut created.
Set to true or false.

startMenuShortcut=

End - Windows Only Options


SPECIFY PRODUCTS YOU WANT TO INSTALL 

By default, the installer installs all the products and 
documentation for which you are licensed. Products you are not licensed for 
are not installed, even if they are listed here.

To install specific products, uncomment the line for the product(s) you want
to install.

product.Aerospace_Blockset
product.Aerospace_Toolbox
product.Bioinformatics_Toolbox
product.Communications_System_Toolbox
product.Computer_Vision_System_Toolbox
product.Control_System_Toolbox
product.Curve_Fitting_Toolbox
product.DO_Qualification_Kit
product.DSP_System_Toolbox
product.Data_Acquisition_Toolbox
product.Database_Toolbox
product.Datafeed_Toolbox
product.EDA_Simulator_Link
product.Econometrics_Toolbox
product.Embedded_Coder
product.Filter_Design_HDL_Coder
product.Financial_Derivatives_Toolbox
product.Financial_Toolbox
product.Fixed_Income_Toolbox
product.Fixed_Point_Toolbox
product.Fuzzy_Logic_Toolbox
product.Gauges_Blockset
product.Global_Optimization_Toolbox
product.IEC_Certification_Kit
product.Image_Acquisition_Toolbox
product.Image_Processing_Toolbox
product.Instrument_Control_Toolbox
product.MATLAB
product.MATLAB_Builder_EX
product.MATLAB_Builder_JA
product.MATLAB_Builder_NE
product.MATLAB_Coder
product.MATLAB_Compiler
product.MATLAB_Distributed_Computing_Server
product.MATLAB_Report_Generator
product.Mapping_Toolbox
product.Model_Predictive_Control_Toolbox
product.Model_Based_Calibration_Toolbox
product.Neural_Network_Toolbox
product.OPC_Toolbox
product.Optimization_Toolbox
product.Parallel_Computing_Toolbox
product.Partial_Differential_Equation_Toolbox
product.Phased_Array_System_Toolbox
product.RF_Toolbox
product.Real_Time_Windows_Target
product.Robust_Control_Toolbox
product.Signal_Processing_Toolbox
product.SimBiology
product.SimDriveline
product.SimElectronics
product.SimEvents
product.SimHydraulics
product.SimMechanics
product.SimPowerSystems
product.SimRF
product.Simscape
product.Simulink
product.Simulink_3D_Animation
product.Simulink_Coder
product.Simulink_Control_Design
product.Simulink_Design_Optimization
product.Simulink_Design_Verifier
product.Simulink_Fixed_Point
product.Simulink_HDL_Coder
product.Simulink_PLC_Coder
product.Simulink_Report_Generator
product.Simulink_Verification_and_Validation
product.Spreadsheet_Link_EX
product.Stateflow
product.Statistics_Toolbox
product.Symbolic_Math_Toolbox
product.System_Identification_Toolbox
product.SystemTest
product.Vehicle_Network_Toolbox
product.Wavelet_Toolbox
product.xPC_Target
product.xPC_Target_Embedded_Option


But it shows error that 
root@LABE-1294-0-170:/home/umeshkumar/Desktop/mat# ./installer
./installer: line 169: product.Aerospace_Blockset: command not found
./installer: line 170: product.Aerospace_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 171: product.Bioinformatics_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 172: product.Communications_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 173: product.Computer_Vision_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 174: product.Control_System_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 175: product.Curve_Fitting_Toolbox: command not found
./installer: line 176: product.DO_Qualification_Kit: command not found
```

Comment: It would be better to add this information to your original question http://askubuntu.com/questions/417584/unable-to-install-matlab-2011-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts